# Android OPEN spinner with single button click

Tags: android, spinner

I have implemented button which clicks and opens dialog with spinner inside as described [here](http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/dialog-box-with-spinner-view-in-android-t1485.html)

However this is two clicks.  One to open dialog and one to open spinner.  I want the spinner to open with a single click of the button?  How can this be done?

Is there anyway to just open spinner from button click w/o going to dialog.  If not how can I open dialog view and have the spinner open at same time.

Comment: Could you paste some of your code/XML? I think the above example should work.

Comment: It works, but the problem is when I click on the button it shows dialog with spinner inside.  So its two clicks not one

Comment: By comparison when I click on spinner itself it comes up immediately.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just put this in your button.onClick

```
spinner.performClick();
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a spinner in your activity with 0 height and 0 width in your xml, then the onItemSelected will work